# Web.xml as Error page by default

Tags: java, xml, servlets, web.xml

[web.xml as error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKBS0.png)

I am using Dynamic project in eclipse
And Annotations for jsp, servlet mapping in servlet pages and i am getting error in web.xml file but it not showing the error and when i run my project getting error as 404 i not used web.xml file

Comment: What is your question? Please also read [mcve] and also [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Add your configuration and stack trace( Console error) .

Comment: @Sumesh TG,HTTP Status 404 – Not Found
Type Status Report

Message /Application1/ViewCount

Description The origin server did not find a current representation for the target resource or is not willing to disclose that one exists.

Apache Tomcat/8.5.32

Comment: Without web.xml how you configured? Are you using spring boot ?

Comment: @Sumesh TG, I am using Annotation @WebServlet("/ViewCount") in servlet page

Comment: Please check `project -> properties-project facets- Dynamic web module` version . It should higher than 3.

Comment: yes it is already checked

Comment: Are you using maven @Chandu

Comment: No, In eclipse i created dynamic web project

Comment: ok Please check your webapp folder is in the build path.

Comment: @Sumesh TG, Yes i got it Thanq